# Django using FTP for large files

Tags: python, django, ftp, django-storage

I'm using Django admin to upload large files into another server ( A download host ).
The files are usually 100mb.
I'm using FTP currently based on [this](https://github.com/jschneier/django-storages/blob/master/storages/backends/ftp.py).
It works fine with files less than 1mb but as it itself says in the documentation, it doesn't work with larger files and I get a 503 when the upload finishes in the Django admin.
I really searched a lot about another way to to this but it  seems there is no other way in Django.
can you help me?

This is my settings.py

```
FTP_STORAGE_LOCATION = 'ftp://<myuser>:<mypass>@<host>:<port>/[path]'
```

my models.py

```
from . import ftp
fs = ftp.FTPStorage()


def my_awesome_upload_function(instance, filename):
     return os.path.join('public_ftp/public/{}/'.format(instance.get_directory()), filename)

class Video(models.Model):
    video_file_ftp = models.FileField(upload_to = my_awesome_upload_function, storage=fs)
```

this is ftp.py

```
# FTP storage class for Django pluggable storage system.
# Author: Rafal Jonca <jonca.rafal@gmail.com>
# License: MIT
# Comes from http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/1269/
#
# Usage:
#
# Add below to settings.py:
# FTP_STORAGE_LOCATION = '[a]ftp://<user>:<pass>@<host>:<port>/[path]'
#
# In models.py you can write:
# from FTPStorage import FTPStorage
# fs = FTPStorage()
# class FTPTest(models.Model):
#     file = models.FileField(upload_to='a/b/c/', storage=fs)

import ftplib
import io
import os
from datetime import datetime
from urllib.parse import urljoin, urlparse

from django.conf import settings
from django.core.exceptions import ImproperlyConfigured
from django.core.files.base import File
from django.core.files.storage import Storage
from django.utils.deconstruct import deconstructible

from storages.utils import setting


class FTPStorageException(Exception):
    pass


@deconstructible
class FTPStorage(Storage):
    """FTP Storage class for Django pluggable storage system."""

    def __init__(self, location=None, base_url=None, encoding=None):
        location = location or setting('FTP_STORAGE_LOCATION')
        if location is None:
            raise ImproperlyConfigured("You must set a location at "
                                       "instanciation or at "
                                       " settings.FTP_STORAGE_LOCATION'.")
        self.location = location
        self.encoding = encoding or setting('FTP_STORAGE_ENCODING') or 'latin-1'
        base_url = base_url or settings.MEDIA_URL
        self._config = self._decode_location(location)
        self._base_url = base_url
        self._connection = None

    def _decode_location(self, location):
        """Return splitted configuration data from location."""
        splitted_url = urlparse(location)
        config = {}

        if splitted_url.scheme not in ('ftp', 'aftp'):
            raise ImproperlyConfigured(
                'FTPStorage works only with FTP protocol!'
            )
        if splitted_url.hostname == '':
            raise ImproperlyConfigured('You must at least provide hostname!')

        if splitted_url.scheme == 'aftp':
            config['active'] = True
        else:
            config['active'] = False
        config['path'] = splitted_url.path
        config['host'] = splitted_url.hostname
        config['user'] = splitted_url.username
        config['passwd'] = splitted_url.password
        config['port'] = int(splitted_url.port)

        return config

    def _start_connection(self):
        # Check if connection is still alive and if not, drop it.
        if self._connection is not None:
            try:
                self._connection.pwd()
            except ftplib.all_errors:
                self._connection = None

        # Real reconnect
        if self._connection is None:
            ftp = ftplib.FTP()
            ftp.encoding = self.encoding
            try:
                ftp.connect(self._config['host'], self._config['port'])
                ftp.login(self._config['user'], self._config['passwd'])
                if self._config['active']:
                    ftp.set_pasv(False)
                if self._config['path'] != '':
                    ftp.cwd(self._config['path'])
                self._connection = ftp
                return
            except ftplib.all_errors:
                raise FTPStorageException(
                    'Connection or login error using data %s'
                    % repr(self._config)
                )

    def disconnect(self):
        self._connection.quit()
        self._connection = None

    def _mkremdirs(self, path):
        pwd = self._connection.pwd()
        path_splitted = path.split(os.path.sep)
        for path_part in path_splitted:
            try:
                self._connection.cwd(path_part)
            except ftplib.all_errors:
                try:
                    self._connection.mkd(path_part)
                    self._connection.cwd(path_part)
                except ftplib.all_errors:
                    raise FTPStorageException(
                        'Cannot create directory chain %s' % path
                    )
        self._connection.cwd(pwd)
        return

    def _put_file(self, name, content):
        # Connection must be open!
        try:
            self._mkremdirs(os.path.dirname(name))
            pwd = self._connection.pwd()
            self._connection.cwd(os.path.dirname(name))
            self._connection.storbinary('STOR ' + os.path.basename(name),
                                        content.file,
                                        content.DEFAULT_CHUNK_SIZE)
            self._connection.cwd(pwd)
        except ftplib.all_errors:
            raise FTPStorageException('Error writing file %s' % name)

    def _open(self, name, mode='rb'):
        remote_file = FTPStorageFile(name, self, mode=mode)
        return remote_file

    def _read(self, name):
        memory_file = io.BytesIO()
        try:
            pwd = self._connection.pwd()
            self._connection.cwd(os.path.dirname(name))
            self._connection.retrbinary('RETR ' + os.path.basename(name),
                                        memory_file.write)
            self._connection.cwd(pwd)
            memory_file.seek(0)
            return memory_file
        except ftplib.all_errors:
            raise FTPStorageException('Error reading file %s' % name)

    def _save(self, name, content):
        content.open()
        self._start_connection()
        self._put_file(name, content)
        content.close()
        return name

    def _get_dir_details(self, path):
        # Connection must be open!
        try:
            lines = []
            self._connection.retrlines('LIST ' + path, lines.append)
            dirs = {}
            files = {}
            for line in lines:
                words = line.split()
                if len(words) < 6:
                    continue
                if words[-2] == '->':
                    continue
                if words[0][0] == 'd':
                    dirs[words[-1]] = 0
                elif words[0][0] == '-':
                    files[words[-1]] = int(words[-5])
            return dirs, files
        except ftplib.all_errors:
            raise FTPStorageException('Error getting listing for %s' % path)

    def modified_time(self, name):
        self._start_connection()
        resp = self._connection.sendcmd('MDTM ' + name)
        if resp[:3] == '213':
            s = resp[3:].strip()
            # workaround for broken FTP servers returning responses
            # starting with e.g. 1904... instead of 2004...
            if len(s) == 15 and s[:2] == '19':
                s = str(1900 + int(s[2:5])) + s[5:]
            return datetime.strptime(s, '%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
        raise FTPStorageException(
                'Error getting modification time of file %s' % name
        )

    def listdir(self, path):
        self._start_connection()
        try:
            dirs, files = self._get_dir_details(path)
            return list(dirs.keys()), list(files.keys())
        except FTPStorageException:
            raise

    def delete(self, name):
        if not self.exists(name):
            return
        self._start_connection()
        try:
            self._connection.delete(name)
        except ftplib.all_errors:
            raise FTPStorageException('Error when removing %s' % name)

    def exists(self, name):
        self._start_connection()
        try:
            nlst = self._connection.nlst(
                os.path.dirname(name) + '/'
            )
            if name in nlst or os.path.basename(name) in nlst:
                return True
            else:
                return False
        except ftplib.error_temp:
            return False
        except ftplib.error_perm:
            # error_perm: 550 Can't find file
            return False
        except ftplib.all_errors:
            raise FTPStorageException('Error when testing existence of %s'
                                      % name)

    def size(self, name):
        self._start_connection()
        try:
            dirs, files = self._get_dir_details(os.path.dirname(name))
            if os.path.basename(name) in files:
                return files[os.path.basename(name)]
            else:
                return 0
        except FTPStorageException:
            return 0

    def url(self, name):
        if self._base_url is None:
            raise ValueError("This file is not accessible via a URL.")
        return urljoin(self._base_url, name).replace('\\', '/')


class FTPStorageFile(File):
    def __init__(self, name, storage, mode):
        self.name = name
        self._storage = storage
        self._mode = mode
        self._is_dirty = False
        self.file = io.BytesIO()
        self._is_read = False

    @property
    def size(self):
        if not hasattr(self, '_size'):
            self._size = self._storage.size(self.name)
        return self._size

    def readlines(self):
        if not self._is_read:
            self._storage._start_connection()
            self.file = self._storage._read(self.name)
            self._is_read = True
        return self.file.readlines()

    def read(self, num_bytes=None):
        if not self._is_read:
            self._storage._start_connection()
            self.file = self._storage._read(self.name)
            self._is_read = True
        return self.file.read(num_bytes)

    def write(self, content):
        if 'w' not in self._mode:
            raise AttributeError("File was opened for read-only access.")
        self.file = io.BytesIO(content)
        self._is_dirty = True
        self._is_read = True

    def close(self):
        if self._is_dirty:
            self._storage._start_connection()
            self._storage._put_file(self.name, self)
            self._storage.disconnect()
        self.file.close()
```

I just simply get the 503 service unavailable on my browser when I try to upload large files. but with less than 1mb files everything works.

Comment: Show us the deployment, related setting and code and the full error traceback!

Comment: For such a large size, I am not sure FTP is the way to go forward. From the docs `This FTP storage is not prepared to work with large files, because it uses memory for temporary data storage.` as such I would recommend using HTTP for this case.  you can also split your files into chunks (not exceeding the threshold) and then sequentially transmit them and figure a way to use them in a compound manner